Etymology of "Finger Sandwiches" [closed as opinion based]
My question (Etymology of "Finger Sandwiches") was closed as opinion based. I'm not a regular here, so if anybody has any feedback on how I could improve it, let me know.
In my personal view, I don't think it's opinion-based at all. I'm not asking "what do people mean by finger sandwiches", I'm asking a question about whether we can trace the historical usage of the word. The answer might be "no, the origin is lost to time" or "It's not definitive, but this early source claims it's in this sense", but that's still a correct, non-opinion-based answer, no?
E.g. I think this answer includes some early usages of "fingers of x", which shows that that origin is at least plausible. That isn't opinion-based, right?

1839 Mons. de Beaureste partook of his coffee and fingers of toast. H. de la Pasture, Real Pearls in False Setting vol. I. iv. 110

I don't really care that the question is reopened--if experienced users feel it's just not suited for the site, I'm happy to let it die. But if there's a tweak I could make to the wording that you think would attract better, less opinion-based answers, I'm happy to edit it.

I agree that it's nonsensical to close as opinion-based. The question is about the etymology and derivation of a fairly recent phrase. Most etymology questions are at risk of being too easily researchable to be a good question, with anything not in the obvious public sources having no good answer except "it's unknown at this time". But that's not called out in the community guidelines as a problem, and it's definitely not an opinion issue.

@JayMcEh Yeah, I will say that I think one of the best bits of SE is occasionally you get an original-research answer 2 years later from somebody who's like "oh I'm doing my grad student dissertation on something similar", so I don't think that 'unanswerable at this time' is that bad a problem. But etymology questions do also seem like they fall into "potentially never answerable" so I understand if people feel that makes them low-quality

I agree with you, and I've even stated similar points before. I think we're overdue for a broader discussion about what "opinion-based" means and should be used for. (Does anyone remember the Help Center text? every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” Does anyone remember the difference between good subjective and bad subjective?)
For now, however, I've reopened the question.

I think some people are confused and believe questions where there is disagreement among experts about the answer are"opinion based" in the Stack Exchange sense because it's hard to choose the "correct" answer. "All answers are equally valid" is not the same thing as "there are several valid answers". If the only valid questions here are questions where there is only one correct answer, every single [tag:single-word-requests] question needs to get tossed ;)

See What is wrong with a discussion of opinion?.
